# Sending Facebook message as specific page

Tags: facebook, xmpp

I've facebook account and a fan page defined within this account.
I'm using XMPP to send private messages using the following Java code
http://yauritux.wordpress.com/2011/09/24/facebook-chat-with-smack-xmpp-api/

I can easily send and receive messages using my user id and password.
However when I try to use my page user ID I'm getting the following error:
SASL authentication PLAIN failed: not-authorized (stack below).
I tried to use pidgin but I'm getting the same error.

Let me know if you've a solution or direction on how to send a message as a page and not as a user.

Thank you in advance,
Moshe

SASL authentication PLAIN failed: not-authorized: 
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication.authenticate(SASLAuthentication.java:337)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.login(XMPPConnection.java:203)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.Connection.login(Connection.java:348)
    at com.maiff.was.connectors.impl.fb.FBConsoleChatApp.login(FBConsoleChatApp.java:55)
    at com.maiff.was.connectors.test.ConnectorTestMain.initFB(ConnectorTestMain.java:55)
    at com.maiff.was.connectors.test.ConnectorTestMain.main(ConnectorTestMain.java:18)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pages can only "reply" to user messages, and i am not sure if it even works with XMPP. Keep in mind that the Chat API is deprecated btw: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/

Meaning, after April 2015 it will not work anymore, not even with users.

**For Page conversations, there is a specific API endpoint to reply to messages: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/conversation/messages**

Comment: Thank you. But even if I want only to reply I need to login. The issue is that once I'm log in with this user it give me not-authorized error

Comment: i don´t think you can use the chat api for pages, to be honest. i will add some more information to my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot using conversations Graph API I could solve this. You did it!